# Python class properties for dictionaries/arrays

Tags: python, dictionary, properties, getter, setter

I am working with dynamic data sets in python and I would like to store them in a dictionary that automatically updates several other variables and automatically does data analysis on the new/updated part of the data only. I'm trying to solve this by saving the data in a dictionary, and then using a getter/setter to update it, but it's not calling the setter when I update dictionary entries.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        # initial data
        self._datadict = dict([['A', 3]])
        # initial analysis
        self.squared = dict([[key, value ** 2] for key, value in self._datadict.items()])

    @property
    def datadict(self):
        print('\t**accessed**')
        return self._datadict
    
    @datadict.setter
    def datadict(self, key, entry):
        print('working...')
        # update data
        self._datadict[key] = entry
        # do analysis on updated part
        self.squared[key] = entry ** 2
        
# initialize class
D = MyClass()

print('Initial:')
print('data:   ', D.datadict)
print('squared:', D.squared)

# Update data
D.datadict['A'] = 4

print('\nAfter update:')
print('data:   ', D.datadict)
print('squared:', D.squared)
```

The output is:

```
Initial:
    **accessed**
data:    {'A': 3}
squared: {'A': 9}
    **accessed**

After update:
    **accessed**
data:    {'A': 4}
squared: {'A': 9}
```

The getter seems to work just fine (as seen by the "**accessed**"), but the setter is not called at all, and while the data itself is updated, it does not update the data analysis "self.squared" attribute.

How can I fix this? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The setter is for the *attribute*. It doesn't control how the dictionary works. `D.datadict['A'] = 4` calls the getter to resolve `D.datadict`, then `dict.__setitem__` is used.

Comment: The most straight-forward way to get this all to work cleanly is to provide an API for your class that doesn't rely on `instance.datadict[key] = value` as your interface, instead, use something like `def update_key(self, key, value)`